# NodeJS to android app communication

Tags: android, node.js

I'm making a NodeJS server and an Android app that goes with it. I need to send alerts to my mobile app users that's coming from the web server. Something like a a chat app on the server and the android users getting the messages also (Facebook messenger?).

I have the server ready and Android app communicating to its database (for user login/getting user info/etc) using REST. I just need to figure out how to send info to the Android app WITH THE SERVER INITIATING COMMUNICATION. Any advice on where to start?

Comment: If you wanna finish it quickly https://www.firebase.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by looking at Google Cloud Messaging.

It's a free service that accepts messages from your server-based program and queues it to be sent to phones with your app when the phones are online.

[Here is the overview on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

YES!

Working with NodeJS, you have probably already heard of [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/).

I'd say: Start there!

For your app to communicate with the server, there's also the [java lib](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java). These are great tools to start making any good real time service.

After you get along with this, you should also check [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) as @krisLarson suggested. And talkign about GCM, you have [Node-GCM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm) to make your work even easier.

Good luck!